# How to make sure that players of tic tac toe game don't fill an already filled board in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game all on my own, I made everything including
Who won and if there is a draw or not, The problem is I failed to find a way to not make
Any players overwrite a specific position in a 2D array
In the main program I used a loop to fill the board from each player and as I said
I tried hard to find a way to not make a player accidentally fill an already filled board
please help and thank you
Here is the code in OOP in a console application

```
class Player
{
    public int player1 { get; set; }
    public int player2 { get; set; }
    public int GetPlayer1(Board board)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Player 1,chose from the above numbers to Print X on the specific position: ");
            player1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (player1 < 0 || player1 > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again and enter a valid number");
            }
            
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        return player1;
    }
    public int GetPlayer2(Board board)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Player 2,chose from the above numbers to Print O on the specific position: ");
            player2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (player2 < 0 || player2 > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again and enter a valid number");
            }
            
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return player2;
    }



 class Board
{

    public Player players = new Player();
    public readonly char[,] gamee = new char[3, 3];
 

    public char GetStateOfFirstPlayer(Board board)
    {
        
       
            players.GetPlayer1(board);


        return players.player1 switch
        {
            1 => gamee[0, 0] = 'X',
            2 => gamee[0, 1] = 'X',
            3 => gamee[0, 2] = 'X',
            4 => gamee[1, 0] = 'X',
            5 => gamee[1, 1] = 'X',
            6 => gamee[1, 2] = 'X',
            7 => gamee[2, 0] = 'X',
            8 => gamee[2, 1] = 'X',
            9 => gamee[2, 2] = 'X',
            _ => '0',

        };




    }
    public char GetStateOfSecondPlayer(Board board)
    {


        

        
            players.GetPlayer2(board);

        return players.player2 switch
        {
            1 => gamee[0, 0] = 'O',
            2 => gamee[0, 1] = 'O',
            3 => gamee[0, 2] = 'O',
            4 => gamee[1, 0] = 'O',
            5 => gamee[1, 1] = 'O',
            6 => gamee[1, 2] = 'O',
            7 => gamee[2, 0] = 'O',
            8 => gamee[2, 1] = 'O',
            9 => gamee[2, 2] = 'O',
            _ => '0',
        };


    }

    public void PrintBoard()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {gamee[0, 0]}   |{gamee[0, 1]}   |{gamee[0, 2]}");

        Console.WriteLine($" {gamee[1, 0]}   |{gamee[1, 1]}   |{gamee[1, 2]}");

        Console.WriteLine($" {gamee[2, 0]}   |{gamee[2, 1]}   |{gamee[2, 2]}");


    }
    static public void BoardNumbers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" (1)   |(2)   |(3)");

        Console.WriteLine($" (4)   |(5)   |(6)");

        Console.WriteLine($" (7)   |(8)   |(9)");

    }

    


}
```

class WinCondition
{

```
    static public bool IsFirstPlayerWon(Board board)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < board.gamee.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < board.gamee.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (board.gamee[x, 0] == 'X' && board.gamee[x, 1] == 'X' && board.gamee[x, 2] == 'X') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, y] == 'X' && board.gamee[1, y] == 'X' && board.gamee[2, y] == 'X') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, 0] == 'X' && board.gamee[1, 1] == 'X' && board.gamee[2, 2] == 'X') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, 2] == 'X' && board.gamee[1, 1] == 'X' && board.gamee[2, 0] == 'X') return true;

            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    static public bool IsSecondPlayerWon(Board board)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < board.gamee.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < board.gamee.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (board.gamee[x, 0] == 'O' && board.gamee[x, 1] == 'O' && board.gamee[x, 2] == 'O') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, y] == 'O' && board.gamee[1, y] == 'O' && board.gamee[2, y] == 'O') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, 0] == 'O' && board.gamee[1, 1] == 'O' && board.gamee[2, 2] == 'O') return true;
                if (board.gamee[0, 2] == 'O' && board.gamee[1, 1] == 'O' && board.gamee[2, 0] == 'O') return true;

            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    static public bool IsDraw(Board board)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if (board.gamee[x, y] == '\0') return false;// default value of char
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Board board = new Board();
        Board.BoardNumbers();
        Player player = new Player();
        for(var x=1;x<=6;x++)
        {
            if(WinCondition.IsDraw(board)==true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Draw");
            }
            board.GetStateOfFirstPlayer(board);
            board.PrintBoard();
            if(WinCondition.IsFirstPlayerWon(board)==true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Player Won");
            }
            board.GetStateOfSecondPlayer(board);
            board.PrintBoard();
            if (WinCondition.IsSecondPlayerWon(board) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second Player Won");
            }

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're way over-complicating things.  All you need is a A) "Board" class, with B) a 3x3 array of squares, each of which has a value of C) 0: free, 1: player1, or 2: player2.  For each turn, you simply ensure the selected square is "free".  Easy peasy!

Comment: can you give me an example in pseudo code at least?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/tic-tac-toe-game-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice start, programming is difficult, but you came very far.

I created an Index class for you, it basically allows to calculate the array indices for your gamee array based on the number the player enters. If the player enters 3, you get x = 2, y=0. Therefore the switch satement is no longer required, and it's easier to check if the board is free at the position.

The new workflow now is like this:

1. Get a number from the player
2. Get the array indices for the number the player entered
3. Check that the board is empty at that point. If not, go to step 1
4. If it is empty, place the player there

Here's a new Index class which helps with the calculation

```
    class Index
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Index(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public static Index GetIndexFromNumber(int number)
        {
            // remove one from the number, required for the following calculation
            int zeroBasedNumber = number - 1;

            // Use modulo board width to get the remainder, this is the x value
            int x = zeroBasedNumber % 3;

            // Use division board height to get the row, this is the y value
            int y = zeroBasedNumber / 3;

            return new Index(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Here's the new GetStateOfPlayer method, it can be used for both players

```
   public void GetStateOfPlayer(Board board, char playerChar)
        {

            Index index;
            do
            {
                players.GetPlayer1(board);
                index = Index.GetIndexFromNumber(players.player1);
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (gamee[index.y, index.x] != '\0')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't place your mark there");
                }
                // Repeat until the field is actually empty
            } while (gamee[index.y, index.x] != '\0');

            // Place it when it's clear
            gamee[index.y, index.x] = playerChar;
        }
```

The main method now looks like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Board board = new Board();
        Board.BoardNumbers();
        Player player = new Player();
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++)
        {
            if (IsDraw(board) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Draw");
            }
            board.GetStateOfPlayer(board, 'X');
            board.PrintBoard();
            if (IsFirstPlayerWon(board) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Player Won");
            }
            board.GetStateOfPlayer(board, 'O');
            board.PrintBoard();
            if (IsSecondPlayerWon(board) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second Player Won");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, am a beginner with no  background about programming
started it 3 months was hard at the begining but now i think am doing good
i know i need 1 or 2 years to be good but i will never give up thank you so much